# How to convert dictionary to pandas DataFrame in Python when dictionary value is a List?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I want to convert Python dictionary into DataFrame. Dictionary value is a List with different length.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1], 'B': [1,2], 'C': [1,2,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

But, the above code doesn't work with the following error:

```
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

The output that I would like to get is as follows:

```
name    value    
'A'      [1]         
'B'      [1,2]
'C'      [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':data.keys(), 'value':data.values()})
print (df)
  name      value
0    A        [1]
1    B     [1, 2]
2    C  [1, 2, 3]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['name','value'])
print (df)
  name      value
0    A        [1]
1    B     [1, 2]
2    C  [1, 2, 3]
```

Also working Series:

```
s = pd.Series(data)

print (s)
A          [1]
B       [1, 2]
C    [1, 2, 3]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

just wrap your dict into list inside Dataframe as shown below

```
import pandas as pd

response_Data = {'name': 'jhon', 'status': 'active'}
mydf = pd.DataFrame([response_Data])
```